# Finding specific div with class using pure JS (no jquery)

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to find a specific div with class using pure javascript but its not giving me result, so I need advise of experts. Here is my html

```
<div class="search">
<center><h1>Search Content</h1></center>
</div>
```

This is the javascript code I am trying;

```
  if(document.div.className.match('search')){
     console.log("Found");
  } else {
     console.log("Not Found");
     }
```

I tried using .classList but it's not supported on IE.10 , so is there any way I can find my required output using pure js?

Here is demo -> https://jsfiddle.net/05aj58nj/

Comment: If you are trying to find a specific element, you shouldn't use classes but ids instead.

Comment: @MinusFour actually the id is not available, I only have class available, and unfortunately I don't have access to add id there :(

Comment: That's fine really. It's just that there's nothing unique about a `div` with a specific class, so you might end up selecting the wrong `div` if you have multiples matches.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The more common way is to use

```
document.getElementsByClassName("search");
```

I find this to be more descriptive and clear.

Comment: This will select all elements though including non divs.

Comment: the only one thing with this method is remember that it returns `array` of elements with such class

Comment: Actually, @Andrew is incorrect. The method returns an HTMLCollection rather than an array. There are important differences between those two objects, and you may want to convert the result to a real array before processing it. But if you just want the first match, then `[0]` will work just fine.

Answer (score 3):

Can you try: `document.querySelectorAll`? This is the right way to do it using Pure JavaScript.

```
document.querySelectorAll("div.search")[0];
document.getElementsByClassName("search")[0];
```

In the `getElementsByClassName` you can check if the type of the element is a `<div>`.

```
<h3 class="search">Head</h3>
<div class="search">Item 1</div>
<div class="search">Item 2</div>
<script>
  a = document.getElementsByClassName("search");
  for (i = 0; i < a.length; i++)
    if (a[i].localName.toLowerCase == "div")
      console.dir(a[i]);
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

`document.getElementsByClassName('classname')`

...or...

`document.querySelectorAll('.classname')`

`getElementsByClassName` will return an `HTMLCollection`, but `querySelectorAll` will return a `NodeList`. If you ever need to iterate over any of them, you can use this convert them to arrays.

`Array.prototype.slice.apply( document.querySelectorAll('.classname') )`